# Is it possible to change material design icon color from xml in Android?

Tags: android, icons, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm actually trying to use colored icons in my app. I've downloaded the official material design icon pack from [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components). Now all the icons in this pack are either white, grey or black. But I want the icons to be of a different color.
Something like the icons on the left side in [this image](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/contacts2-2.png). The phone phone and mail icons are blue. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you  try something like android:background="@color/red" ?

Comment: As the icon file is in .png format, you should change the color using the tool from which you've created icon. and add it using ImageAsset into project .

Comment: @rajatIIT 
android:background makes a red box around the icon, and the icon still remains grey in color.

Comment: What is your minimum target API?

Comment: in github we have the svg files for the icons, can we derive colour icons from there ?

Answer (score 59):

For changing icon color try

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="your value"
    android:layout_height="your value"
    /* and so on ... */

    android:tint="YourColor"
    />
```

Note: the tint color is painted ontop of the image, not a replacement color. So tint `#80ff0000` on a black image gives you 50 % red on black, not 50 % red on the background. I.e. this is not equivalent to iOS template images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `TintImageView` within the appcompat support library and then tinting/coloring the imageview is by simply calling the  `android:backgroundTint` to tint the imageview into one color.

---

**Xml**

```
<TintImageView
android:layout_width=""
android:layout_height="" 
android:src=""
android:backgroundTint="@color/green"/>
```

or

```
<ImageView 
android:tint="the_color_you_want"/>
```

---

**Programatically**

`ImageView yourImageView = findViewById(...)
 yourImageView.setColorFilter(Context.getColor(your_color_here))`

---

So the above xml will tint the imageView to color green, means that it will colorize each pixel of the imageview that are visible to green.

Comment: if I want to change the drawable left|right icon  Tint for EditText TextView there no way to do that I feel! *android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"* not works !!

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for the same thing but to change it dynamically in the code.  I hope this helps someone looking for the same thing.

Create an ImageView for the icon and use setColorFilter on that view.

```
ImageView imageViewIcon = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
imageViewIcon.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<vector android:height="48dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="48dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ca0f0f" android:pathData="M3,5v14c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2H5c-1.11,0 -2,0.9 -2,2zm12,4c0,1.66 -1.34,3 -3,3s-3,-1.34 -3,-3 1.34,-3 3,-3 3,1.34 3,3zm-9,8c0,-2 4,-3.1 6,-3.1s6,1.1 6,3.1v1H6v-1z"/>
</vector>
```

you change color by changing android:fillColor="#ca0f0f"

Answer (score 2):

How to change material icon color in XML

```
<ImageButton 
     android:layout_width="YourValue"
     android:layout_height="YourValue"
     ...
     android:tint="YourColor" // this line do the magic
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many alternatives here already in this thread. Perhaps I can add one more for whoever finds it convenient :

You can also use the Drawable class, the code being as follows

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Although the above did the trick for me, but for my use case suggicient was to use `android:tint`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and it's simple using this library:
https://github.com/jrvansuita/IconHandler

You can easily call this:

```
Icon.on(yourImageView).color(R.color.your_color).icon(R.mipmap.your_icon).put();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to modify the colour of your icon from xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:foregroundTintMode="src_over"
    android:tint="Your colour"
    ...
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow" 
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding to what Murali said, make multiple drawables with different fill colors.

Then when needed, add to your code:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable_with_different_color)
```

NOT: `imageView.setBackgroundResource()`

Comment: If suppose the icon has to be shown in 200 different colors, then will you put 200 icons with different colors in your drawable?