# How to set color for imageview in Android

Tags: android

I want set icon into `ImageView` and i downloaded icons from this site : [FlatIcon](http://www.flaticon.com/)
Now i want set color to this icons but when use `setBackground` just add color for background and not set to icons!
When use `NavigationView` i can set color to icons with this code : `app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"`.

How can i set color to icons into `ImageView` such as `itemIconTint` ? Thanks all <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set tint for an image view programmatically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121938/how-to-set-tint-for-an-image-view-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

If you are using an icon maybe this can be useful:

```
android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
```

Otherwise you can try to modify the class:

```
ImageView imageViewIcon = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
imageViewIcon.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

More info in this thread: [Is it possible to change material design icon color from xml in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790987/is-it-possible-to-change-material-design-icon-color-from-xml-in-android)

Comment: is android 4.0 support android:tint="@color/colorAccent" ?

Comment: If you see getColor as deprecated you need to do following  ```imageViewIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.blue));```

Comment: In that case, color that has alpha could not be applied. For example, if the color is "#90000000", black color will be applied.

Comment: For me "android:tint="@color/colorAccent" was not working so I use "app:tint="@color/colorAccent"

Answer (score 27):

Use tint attribute of ImageView.

```
 android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
```

Comment: is android 4.0 support android:tint="@color/colorAccent" ?

Comment: @MohammadNouri No, color state lists and resource references in the `android:tint` attribute are not supported prior to Android 5.0 (API 21)

Comment: Actually, the ColorStateList has been around since API v1 :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Answer (score 13):

```
 DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 9):

Latest Lint shows a warning using android:tint, recommending to use app:tint, but the tint is not visible until you use it together with app:tintMode. So it looks like this:

```
app:tint="@color/yourcolor"
app:tintMode="add"
```

Comment: In my case, app:tintMode="add" does nothing. Also the effect of app:tint="@color/yourcolor" is also visible at runtime, i.e. cannot see it applied in the designer.

Comment: If "add" doesn't work you can try other [modes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:tintMode)

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this tint imageview in android XML

```
 android:tint="@color/yourcolor"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add this line in your image view.

In XML File:-

```
 android:tint="@color/color_name"

           or


app:tint="@color/color_name"
```

In Java File:-

```
imageViewIconName.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `android:tint`, but since there were some issues in some versions.

use `AppCompatImageView` and it will work fine.

```
<AppCompatImageView 
        android:tint="@color/your_color" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use: `ivMyImageView.setColorFilter(ActivityCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_green_light))`

Answer (score 1):

```
app:tint="@color___"
```

Answer (score 0):

El0din has answered with "**android**:tint="@color/colorAccent""

but you will get an error You Have to change "android" to be "app"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32110418)

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the corresponding comments. No need to add one more answer.

Comment: Ok I just mentioned there will be an error appeared