# how to change src attribute dynamically in android studio?

Tags: android

how can I set src attribute (line 7) dynamically in android studio,I tried to change the backgroundResource but is not the same

XML file

```
<ImageView
    android:onClick="next2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img3"
    android:src="#9d070976"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img2" />
```

Java code

```
a.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor);
```

Comment: `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dynmic_drawble)` or `imageView.setImageDrawble(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.dynmic_drawble))`

Comment: I want to change the color by a new value not by drawable image

Comment: you have to create Colordrawable for that

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/38653357/6559031

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what form your image is in, use:

- [`setImageBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap))
- [`setImageDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
- [`setImageIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon))
- or [`setImageResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))

If your replacement image is in the form of a URL or `Uri` that you need to load, use an image-loading library like Picasso or Glide. They can load the image in the background and fill in the `ImageView` once the image is ready to be displayed.

Comment: I want to change the color  that I difined it in xml fille  by a new value not by drawable image

Comment: @omarohead: Create a `ColorDrawable` for your desired color, then use `setImageDrawable()`.