# Change the color of the icon in the ImageView in the java class

Tags: java, android, imageview

I showed the icons in the program via ImageView. The yellow icons should turn red when the button is pressed. I tried all the methods, but none of them worked. ...Backgroundcolor... He turned ImageView red in full square shape. I just want the icon to change color. This is very difficult‚ Please help. Thank you.

**My code:**

```
ImageView Test = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.TestImageIcon);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Here            
        Test.setcolor(R.id.red);
    }
});
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please post the code where you face an issue. Please make sure to post a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the color of the icon in the ImageView in the java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69948747/change-the-color-of-the-icon-in-the-imageview-in-the-java-class)

Comment: Kindly improve the [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69948747/9636037) if you are not getting any answers. Don't post a duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set color for imageview in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653357/how-to-set-color-for-imageview-in-android)

Comment: Please refer to [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) if you are not sure, "Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general; instead, use the [android] tag.". This question is not related to `android-studio`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you change the tint of drawable like that:

```
 imageView.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: did not work. The color does not change. :(

Comment: try like that bro 
                  
imageView.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using **setColorFilter**(color).

Comment: Would you please write the full code? What to write next? Please.

Comment: Test.setColorFilter(Color.RED);

Comment: Not working :( not change color ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change color of icon programatically with
`Test.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.red));`

Comment: No, unfortunately, this method did not work. the color does not change. :(

Comment: Check for this also on onclick of button
`Test.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red),` 
 `android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

Comment: Color does not change :(