# How to change color of material design icon used in Button in Android

Tags: android, icons, material-design, android-appcompat

I am having this `Button` in my XML:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button_message_me"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.25"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:background="@drawable/ic_chat_white_48dp"
     android:onClick="clickMessageMe"/>
```

However, I want to change the color of `ic_chat_white_48dp` from white to blue. How to do change?

**What I already tried so far:**

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691486/1911652) post, I tried using `android:tint="@color/blue"` but it did not work.

So, thinking that I might need to use `ImageButton` instead of `Button` (as mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691486/1911652)) I replaced `Button` with `ImageButton` in my XML but I landed up getting exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{chat.knowme.knowme/chat.knowme.knowme.ShowProfileActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.Button

Any help would be really appreciated. Many thanks!

**Update:**
The crash was because I was casting the `ImageButton` to `Button`in my source. I fixed it and now doesn't crash anymore (thanks to Patel Pinkal for his answer).

However, color still remain unchanged even with `ImageButton`

Comment: post your `Button` initialize code

Comment: There is no initialize code as such for this button. I've used `(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_message_me);` whenever I wanted to show/hide this button. And have written `clickMessageMe` method for the button. However, crash occurs as soon as I launch the activity.

Comment: What you are using `ImageButton` or `AppCompatImageButton`?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to initialize `Button` instead of `AppCompatImageButton`. Just replace like this

```
 AppCompatImageButton appCompatImageButton = (AppCompatImageButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatImageButton);
```

Instead of :

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

AND

if you want to change color using `Button` or `AppCompatImageButton`, 
 you have to change like

`android:backgroundTint="@Color/yourColor"`

Instead of

`android:tint="@Color/yourColor"`

Comment: Oh I see. Sure I'll try this might be the reason :)

Comment: @Atul try it and review it here

Comment: Well I tried it. Crash disappeared but color still didn't change.

Comment: Not sure if I can post code and layout etc. Need to check. However, I'll try your new suggestion. Thanks mate.

Comment: Nope. Is it only for higher versions? I am getting `Attribute backgroundTint is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 15`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132359/discussion-between-atul-and-patel-pinkal).

Answer (score 3):

I also face this problem. Finally found the solution, using **Android Material Design Icon Generator Plugin**. Through this you can generate icons in various colors and sizes.

**Step1:** File-> Settings->Plugin

**Step2:** Search for android material icon, you will get Android Material Design Icon Generator Plugin in the list

**Step3:** Select that and click Apply

Once its installed, Right click on your project from studio->new->Material design icon or ctrl+alt+M

It will be useful for developers.

Comment: That is nice suggestion indeed. If I couldn't change color through code I'll surely go for this.