# Android Material Design. Tab icon is too dark

Tags: android, material-design

I'm new to Android and i'm making tab bar using Google's `SlidingTabLayout`. I have a question that why does these Icons are too dark. [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQvtK.png)

[image]

help me to understand this

Comment: you are using these icons from drawable folders?

Comment: You can replace them .If you don't know how to go inside your project folder and check them using their names

Comment: I'm using these icons from mipmap folders

Answer (score 1):

In layout xml, You can add

```
android:tint="#FF545454" //Add the color you want
```

Example:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:id="@+id/ic_home
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" 
        android:tint="#FF545454" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://material.io/icons/

Both dark and light versions are available for each icon.

If you want a different colour for the icon, follow this:

[Is it possible to change material design icon color from xml in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790987/is-it-possible-to-change-material-design-icon-color-from-xml-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

***Download other Icons from Google icons site (you can customize their colors) and adjust there colors , and then replace them with the new ones.***

Below is the link .
[Google material design Icons](https://material.io/icons/)