# How to set tint color for ImageView loaded SVG image

Tags: android, svg, android-glide, tint

I tried to load PNG image form drawable into ImageView, and set tint color for this ImageView with below code ⇒ **it's working**:

```
imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pngFile);
imageView1.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I want to load SVG image into ImageView using Glide and set tint color for it.
But after successfully loading SVG image into imageView, **setColorFilter NOT WORKING**.

I could load SVG image into another ImageView using Glide with the below code:

```
// Setup RequestBuilder
requestBuilder = Glide.with(mActivity)
.using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, mActivity), 
InputStream.class)
.from(Uri.class)
.as(SVG.class)
.transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
.sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
.cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SvgDecoder()))
.decoder(new SvgDecoder())
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_facebook)
.error(R.drawable.ic_web)
.animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
.listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());

// Use RequestBuilder with uri
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg");
requestBuilder
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
.load(uri)
.into(imageView2);
```

Now, I want to change tint color of mageView2 (after successfully loading SVG image into imageView2), I tried the below code but **it's not working**:

```
imageView2.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 7):

The complete guide how to download SVG via Glide:

1) Include this libraries in your gradle file:

`implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
 kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"
 implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4`

2) Download files from the [Glide SVG sampler.](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg)

3) Modify the [SvgDrawableTranscoder](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg/SvgDrawableTranscoder.java) class to convert PictureDrawable to BitmapDrawable, because PictureDrawable is not able to apply a color filter:

```
public class SvgDrawableTranscoder implements ResourceTranscoder<SVG, Drawable> {
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public Resource<Drawable> transcode(
      @NonNull Resource<SVG> toTranscode, @NonNull Options options) {
    SVG svg = toTranscode.get();
    Picture picture = svg.renderToPicture();
    PictureDrawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    canvas.drawPicture(drawable.getPicture());
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(PlatformApp.Companion.getInstance().getResources(), returnedBitmap);
    return new SimpleResource<>(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: Best approach till now.

Answer (score 4):

you can set the layer paint of imageview. this is the only method that i found working !

```
val paint = Paint()
val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
paint.colorFilter = colorFilter
imageView.setLayerPaint(paint)
```

this code is in kotlin, just add a few **new** keywords to make it work in java :)

if you are using kotlin, add this extension to make it easier

```
fun ImageView.paintColor(colorString: String) {
    val paint = Paint()
    val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(colorString), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    paint.colorFilter = colorFilter
    setLayerPaint(paint)
}
```

then you only need to call paintColor and voila !

```
imageView.paintColor("#FFC4C4C4")
```

Comment: It just painted the all imageview, even the background

Comment: For me it worked well. The only solution, and easy.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an icon maybe this can be usefull:

```
android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
```

else you can try modify the class:

```
ImageView imageViewIcon = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
imageViewIcon.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

more info in this thread Is it possible to change material design icon color from xml in Android?
[Material design icon colour from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790987/is-it-possible-to-change-material-design-icon-color-from-xml-in-android)

Comment: This solution WORKING when i loaded PNG image form drawable into ImageView. But when i loaded SVG image into imageView using Glide, it's NOT WORKING. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` replace `ImageView`  and using

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(imvageView.getDrawable(), getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));
```

Comment: I tried load PNG image form drawable into ImageView, and using your code to set tint color ⇒ it's working. But after successfully loading SVG image into imageView using Glide, setColorFilter NOT WORKING. 
Another solution?

Comment: What do you mean?. You comment the same for other answers. So Which answer works?

Comment: All three ways WORKING when loaded PNG image form drawable into ImageViewt. But when loaded SVG image into imageView using Glide, all three ways NOT WORKING. Please help !

Comment: @Sonzero Had you got any other solution for loaded SVG color change?

Answer (score 0):

To change icon color, we can use tint

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView 
  // ...
  android:tint="#9997E1" />
```